# In Objective-C, why does setter lead to crash when I user self.propName notation but not when I use _ivarName

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to understand why this crashes when I use `self.propName` notation but not when I use `_ivarName` notation. Happy to learn about another part of Objective-C. Thanks for the help!

```
// .h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface FOOMySpecialClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly, assign) BOOL isFoo;

- (void)setIsFoo:(BOOL)isFoo;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

```
// .m

#import "FOOMySpecialClass.h"

@interface FOOMySpecialClass()
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) BOOL isFoo;
@end

@implementation FOOMySpecialClass

- (void)setIsFoo:(BOOL)isFoo {
    self.isFoo = isFoo; // <-- Crash here
}

@end
```

But, if I change the bool to the ivar, things work fine. I'm trying to understand why.

```
// .m

#import "FOOMySpecialClass.h"

@interface FOOMySpecialClass()
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) BOOL isFoo;
@end

@implementation FOOMySpecialClass

- (void)setIsFoo:(BOOL)isFoo {
    _isFoo = isFoo; // <-- Change here and no crash
}

@end
```

```
// main.m

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "FOOMySpecialClass.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        FOOMySpecialClass *mySpecialClass = [[FOOMySpecialClass alloc] init];
        [mySpecialClass setIsFoo:YES];
        
        NSLog(@"%@", mySpecialClass.isFoo ? @"YES" : @"NO"); // <-- boom.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add a `NSLog(@"Calling setIsFoo:");` at the first line of the method, you'll see: infinite loop, you're calling yourself each time.

Comment: If you rename `- (void)setIsFoo:(BOOL)isFoo;` with `- (void)setIsFoo2:(BOOL)isFoo;`, and do `[mySpecialClass setIsFoo2:YES];`, there won't be a loop anymore. But `self.isFoo = someValue` is equal to `[self setIsFoo:someValue]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Objective-C Property Getter/Setter crash EXC\_BAD\_ACCESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637799/objective-c-property-getter-setter-crash-exc-bad-access)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important lesson here is what "dot syntax" actually means in ObjC. Originally (until around 2007) in ObjC, setting a property was always done using a method called `-setX:`, which would be called as `[obj setThing:thing]`. There was no `obj.thing = thing` syntax. (This existed for C structs, but that's a very different thing.)

This `setThing:` syntax was through convention. It was not actually part of the language, and there were no `@property` definitions. It was just well understood that when you wanted to expose a "writable property" called `thing`, the object should have methods `-thing` and `-setThing:` (plus some subtle rules about BOOL properties and the `is...` prefix, and by-reference `get...` methods that I won't dive into). This all became formalized as [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-BAJEAIEE), but was still technically "convention," not part of the language.

In ObjC 2, the convention was made part of the language as "dot syntax." I do not exaggerate to say this change was extremely controversial. (It is **still** controversial in some circles, but most of us have kind of gotten over it.) With dot syntax, `obj.thing` is translated into `[obj thing]`, and `obj.thing = thing` is translated into `[obj setThing:thing]`. It is purely syntactic sugar.

As a separate feature, over a couple of iterations involving ever-less `@synthesize`, the `@property` syntax was added. This let you define "properties" that would automatically define a backing ivar (with a leading `_`) and the required getter and setter methods to match existing conventions.

So looking at your property definition:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) BOOL isFoo;
```

This, provided that `-isFoo` and `-setIsFoo:` are not defined, will automatically create an ivar called `_isFoo`, and provide synthesized getter and setter methods that apply the requested memory management. (That's another story, leading eventually to ARC.)

But in your case you define `setIsFoo:`, so the setter is not generated automatically. Instead, expanding the dot syntax sugar, you've written:

```
- (void)setIsFoo:(BOOL)isFoo {
    [self setIsFoo:isFoo];
}
```

And, as you might expect, that crashes, since it's infinitely recursive. Accessesing the ivar (`_isFoo`) directly does not crash, and is the correct way to implement this. (Though in this specific case, since you're using the default implementation, you shouldn't write this; you should allow the system to synthesize it for you.)

Answer (score 4):

self.isFoo = isFoo; calls the same setter recursively. So you have an infinite recursion, and that crashes.

Look at the stack in Xcode and you’ll see a gazillion of nested calls to setIsFoo.